# Addresible led delay for 24 hours with arduino uno

Tags: arduino-uno

Im working on a project with my addresible led strip and arduino uno
I need 3 leds on the strip to light for 24 hours and then the next 3 leds on the strip should light up for 24 hours and so on.
Can somone help me with the code

Comment: Can you show us the code you've written so far?

Comment: Im new to arduino if someone can just start me off with the code it will be a big help
Thanks

Comment: I know how to turn on and off.

Comment: @user57550 - Start with the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example that comes with the IDE. Once you have that sketch turning the LED on and off every 24 hours, edit your question and add the sketch.

Comment: @VE7JRO thanks for your jelp

Comment: turn on 3 .. wait 5 seconds ... turn on next 3 ... wait 5 seconds ... repeat .... when you get that going, increase the wait time

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn about [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and how to [format your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).